# How can I use this function?I take it from other project

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to php language. I just copy a database connection function from another sample project. The code is below.

```
public function getRows($conditions = array()){
    $sql = 'SELECT ';
    $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
    $sql .= ' FROM '.$this->table;
    if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' WHERE ';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
            $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by']; 
    }

    if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit']; 
    }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit']; 
    }

    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    if(array_key_exists("return_type",$conditions) && $conditions['return_type'] != 'all'){
        switch($conditions['return_type']){
            case 'count':
                $data = $query->rowCount();
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;
            default:
                $data = '';
        }
    }else{
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            $data = $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
    return !empty($data)?$data:false;
}
```

Can anyone show me example how to use this function?I want to use WHERE,LIMIT,GROUP_BY and SELECT clauses. When I put in an array like this, I got error message " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

```
$conditions = array('where' => "user_name = '$username'");
$data = $userMo -> getRows($conditions);
```

Comment: Try $conditions = array('where' => "user_name = '+$username+'"); this

Comment: thanks I've tried that and It's doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are making a mistake, as its said `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

that means its not getting an array, and think if there are multiple WHERE then??

so try this

```
$conditions = array('where' => array('user_name' => $username));
```

Comment: bro I got a boolean return not data.

Comment: that you need to check in the query, what it will return, try to print the $sql inside the function to see what sql it runs